# Converting Coldfusion to PHP: cgi.query_string

Tags: php, coldfusion, cgi

I am new to programming, and am privileged to have as one of my first assignments the conversion of some CFML to PHP.

```
 <cfif find("tips",cgi.query_string) or find("tip",cgi.query_string)>  
 <li class="current middle"><a class="topnavtext" href="#siteurl#tips">GF Tips</a></li>
 <cfelse><li class="middle"><a class="topnavtext" href="#siteurl#tips">GF Tips</a></li>
 </cfif>
```

Is it looking for "tips" in `cgi.query_string`?

How would that be converted to PHP?

Comment: Yes it's looking for the string tips in the variable, cgi.querystring.  For the php people, cgi.querystring is the collection of url variables.  It would everything after the question mark in "http://a.com?x=1&y=2&frick=frack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is what you need to get the query string.

There is more information available [here](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: All of which would be parsed into entries in the [`$_GET` superglobal array](http://se2.php.net/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: So, would the following work for the if statement?  if (strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "tips")) || if (strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "tip"))

Comment: You would likely be better off checking for a an entry in `$_GET` than searching for a sub-string in the query string. Here is why: lets say the query string is `?type=tipsy` searching for the string 'tips' will return true, where as you may be looking for the URL variable named 'tip' (or 'tips'). Basically, it seems as if the initial logic in the ColdFusion code is less than optimal.

Comment: For all intents and purposes at the moment, I'm stuck doing it this way.  I'm getting a parse error in the if part of the code I'll post below.

Comment: `<?php
define("siteurl", "http://www.site.com");
?>

 <?php
 if (strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "tips")) || if (strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "tip")) {
    echo "<li class=\"current\"><a class=\"topnavtext\" href=\"#siteurl#\">Home</a></li>";
    }
    else {
    echo "<li><a class=\"topnavtext\" href=\"#siteurl#\">Home</a></li>";
   }
   ?> `